# how to paste special data which is stored in variable using in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to paste special data as values which is stored in variable.
I am reading all data from text file and storing in variable "**sText**", when I am pasting this data Excel at Range("A1") it is pasting all values in single cell which I want to avoid.
So, I want to paste special this stored data in Excel, so data will we pasted in different columns and not in single cell.

Is there any way to copy this stored data in variable "**sText**", so I can paste special this data where I need. I am using Excel 2016 version.

Below is VBA code which copies data from text file and paste in excel.

```
Sub CopyLogFilesData()

        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet
        Dim LogFilePath As String
        Dim sText As String

        Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = wb.Sheets("Notepad_Data")
        Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("File_Path")

        'Log File Path
        LogFilePath = ws1.Range("C10").Value

        'Delete Sheet Data
        ws.Activate
        ws.Range("A1:K200").ClearContents

        'Copy data from textFile
        Dim oFso: Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Dim oFile: Set oFile = oFso.OpenTextFile(LogFilePath, 1)

        sText = oFile.ReadAll
        oFile.Close

        ws.Range("A1").Value = sText

End Sub
```

Below is Text file data:

```
INFO]Library export started at Fri Sep 06 14:04:49 GMT+05:30 2019   
[INFO]Library export: Exporting all parts into CSV file : C:\Users\CHS Library growth.csv   
[INFO]Library export: Fetching all parts Fri Sep 06 14:04:55 GMT+05:30 2019 
[INFO]Library export: Started writing parts into file Fri Sep 06 14:05:05 GMT+05:30 2019    
[INFO]Library export ended at Fri Sep 06 14:05:05 GMT+05:30 2019    
[INFO]Number of Connector part(s) received: 25  
[INFO]Number of Connector Seal part(s) received: 15 
[INFO]Number of Solder Sleeve part(s) received: 2   
[INFO]Number of Tube part(s) received: 1
```

Comment: Is the data separated by a comma or some other delimiter in the text file?  You could use [TextToColumns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.TextToColumns) to split it into columns after putting it in A1.

Comment: Yes data is separated by colon(:), and I have tried using TextToColumns but it didn't worked since all data comes in single cell. I have edited the post with text file data, how its look

Comment: You can use the 'split' function to convert it to an array and then past that array directly to the target worksheet but, from memory, you need to specify the correct dimensions of the array when you paste.

Comment: this will be long process, is there any way, we can copy stored variable data and then paste special where we want